# Get the presented Viewcontroller from ReactNative rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, react-native-native-module

In React Native project I want to access the Presented Viewcontroller from iOS npm module. I'm able to access the rootviewcontroller of the RN project using the below code

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
```

But I want the current VC that is presented on top of RootVC so that I should be able to present native(iOS) UINavigationController on top of it.

Note:`[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController` returns nill.

Answer (score 12):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I was running into the same problem today (`[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.presentedViewController` returns `nil`) and couldn't find the solution for a while, so I'll leave this here for anyone still looking.

There's a [function](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/91681016e84cdb99bd823c937762a0d9974e56fe/React/Base/RCTUtils.h#L87) in the React Native source code that allows you to determine the presented view controller. It seems like they use this for their ActionSheetIOS module (see this [line](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0df5e5016da73c1d32ae73739e6669b06d399c0c/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/RCTActionSheetManager.m#L76)). To use this in your own native module, add the following:

```
// Put this near the top of the file
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>

...

// Put this where you need access to the presented view controller
UIViewController *presentedViewController = RCTPresentedViewController();
```

Comment: Note that if you want to access `RCTPresentedViewController` in Swift, you can add the `#import <React/RCTUtils.h>` line to your `<ModuleName>-Bridging-Header.h` file.